# Connecting to a SSAS cube using R

Tags: r, ssas, olap-cube

Is it possible to query a SQL Server Analysis Services cube using R?
I have this cube on a different external Server and i am working from my machine but i have admin privileges on the Server with my domain account.
To put it simply, i want to create an alaysis services solution, suing some mining algorithm to examine data cotained in the Cube. I can do that with Excel, for instance, but i need to use R to take advantage of several interesting clustering algorithms different from those MS offers.
Is that possible? Which package should i import in R?

Answer (score 1):

maybe something is coming from here

https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Importing-MDX-OLAP-cube-data-77616%2ES%2E265568694?view=&gid=77616&item=265568694&type=member&commentID=discussion%3A265568694%3Agroup%3A77616&trk=hb_ntf_COMMENTED_ON_GROUP_DISCUSSION_YOU_COMMENTED_ON&_mSplash=1

at the moment it's not available from CRAN, but maybe you will give it a try.

In the meantime you can also use an ODBC / OLEDB bridge and use the RODBC from inside R.

Hope this helps a little

Tom