# Use RDCOMClient to connect R to SSAS Cube

Tags: r, ssas, ado

I'm trying to establish a connection between R and a Sequel Server Analysis Services (SSAS) Cube. Similar questions have been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140753/connecting-to-a-ssas-cube-using-r/26157100#26157100) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061547/connecting-to-analysis-services-from-r-or-nodejs), but I haven't been able to find an easy answer. HTTP access through the X4R package is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558601/using-x4r-package-in-r-to-connect-to-a-ssas-cube), but the SSAS cube I have access to is not configured for HTTP connections.

Using the [RDCOMClient](http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient/) library, I can create an "ADO Connection" object with

`con <- COMCreate("ADODB.Connection")`

Following the script [here](http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient/examples/RADO.R), I would like to write something like

```
con[["ConnectionString"]] <- paste(
  "Provider=MSOLAP.4",
  "Server=myserver",
  "Initial Catalog=mycatalog",
  sep = ";")
con$Open()
```

to specify the connection string and open the connection. The labels `myserver` and `mycatalog` are set to their appropriate values based on the connection I am able to establish between Excel and SSAS.

However, my connection string is probably not correctly specified because I get the error

```
<checkErrorInfo> 80020009 
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
checkErrorInfo -2147352567
Error: Exception occurred.
```

I don't know how to debug this error either. Could someone advise

1. the appropriate COM class to use (i.e. is "ADODB.Connection" correct?)
2. the key-value pairs required for the "ConnectionString" element of the COM class object
3. where I can find more information about these topics (the [MSDN ADO MD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677552(v=vs.85).aspx) for developers pages are quite difficult for a non-developer)
4. if there is a better way to go about establishing a connection between R and an SSAS Cube

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am getting the same error....

Answer (score 0):

How is the path to "myserver" defined?  I got this error when I confused R and SSAS with backslashes/forward slashes.

I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490516/sending-email-attachement-through-outlook-in-r-with-rdcomclient) to help with correct syntax and then the error disappeared (i.e. I used backwards slashes and added an extra backslash for each one to escape them)